# Xcode Build from Unity3D is generating Game Center Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

Why when I'm trying to build my project on Xcode (The original project was developed on Unity 3D) I got those errors:

```
(null): "__gameCenterShowCompletionBannerForAchievements", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterResetAchievements", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterRetrieveAchievementMetadata", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterGetAchievements", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterShowAchievements", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterRetrieveScoresForPlayerIdAndLeaderboard", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterRetrieveScoresForLeaderboard", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterShowLeaderboardWithTimeScopeAndLeaderboardId", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterShowLeaderboardWithTimeScope", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterRetrieveScoresForPlayerId", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterReportScore", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterRetrieveFriends", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterLoadLeaderboardLeaderboardTitles", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterLoadPlayerData", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterPlayerIdentifier", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterIsPlayerAuthenticated", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterReportAchievement", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterPlayerAlias", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterIsUnderage", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterAuthenticateLocalPlayer", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterRetrieveScores", referenced from:
(null): "__gameCenterIsGameCenterAvailable", referenced from:
(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I have a feeling you are using a plugin and that plugin may be the problem. Any plugins used in the original project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is generated by old Prime31 SDK in Unity which does not support x64 architecture. Update your Prime31 Unity plugin and try again.

Comment: download the latest one and replace in your Unity project